# Package fontenc not working on beamer

Tags: beamer, font-encodings

In LaTeX, using the `\documentclass{article}`, I've used the packages `inputenc` as utf8 and `fontenc` for T1. For papers, these packages have been great in allowing me to type especial characters (in math mode and foreign languages), and the PDF's generated also allow the viewer to copy and paste said special characters.

Now I'm trying to create slides on LaTeX using `\documentclass{beamer}`. However, these packages are not working the same way they do on the article class. While the special characters appear just fine in the frames, I am not able to copy and paste those special characters. Below is a minimal working example.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %removed as suggested my skillmon
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        text... é ñ ç
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

How can I ensure that these special characters can be copied and pasted from the PDF's generated into any other file? I'm using these slides for class, and I need my students to be able to access to all the content in them.

**Update:** log file and pdf links in comments below

Comment: works fine for me in texlive 2021. Is your tex system up-to-date? And are you using type1 font everywhere? (If you don't know show the end of log-file with the font list).

Comment: Yes, TexStudio is up to date and I've added a screenshot of the log file for my minimal working example. Perhaps my problem is expressed there, but I don't know what those logs mean.

Comment: open the real log-file. Probably you get it if you click on the tab saying "log-file". Or look in folder as your tex file for a file with the ending .log. And texstudio is not a texsystem, it is only an editor.

Comment: TeXstudio being up to date isn't the same as your TeX system being up to date. The former is just an editor, the latter is a collection of tools and files.

Comment: By the way, with an up to date TeX system `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` is no longer necessary as that is the default for LaTeX.

Comment: Thanks for those useful details. I've updated to TeXLive 2021, and the issue persists. The symbols appear just fine on the pdf but I can't copy/paste them. And here's the end of my log file: https://pastebin.com/CVTFKbXk. I don't know how to check if I'm using type1 font everywhere.

Comment: the fonts look ok. Show the complete log, and if possible make the pdf available somewhere.

Comment: I cannot duplicate your bug on TeX Live 2021. The `mmap` package is supposed to make T1 and other encodings copyable, but in fact `mmap` and `cmap` break copying when I test them, and it works fine without them.

Comment: I've updated the pastebin to include the whole log file: https://pastebin.com/CVTFKbXk. I've also made my pdf available here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13wAZ_m3O90NBQRom6bD2BmhwBmB2iBj1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I have no problem cutting and pasting the characters from your pdf viewed with adobe reader (under linux): `text... é ñ ç`.  Also I cannot see the size substitution message in you full log.

Comment: @ArTourter, the size substitution message went away after I updated TeXLive. And after reading your response, I tried using mac's preview, and I was able to copy them too `text... é ñ ç`. Does this mean that the problem is with my Adobe Acrobat (how I view my pdf's)? I've checked, and the program is up to date. Any suggestion as to what I can look into to try to fix the problem?

Comment: your latex is a bit older. Try if it works if you add ` \input{glyphtounicode} \pdfgentounicode=1 ` to your preamble.

Comment: I tried the `glyphtounicode` package, and this is what I get: `text...  e ˜n  c`. It did something, but it's not working as intended.